# How to use H1 tag in Jssor slider

Tags: tags, slider, heading

does anyone know how to use a single H1 tag effectively in a [Jssor full width slider](http://www.jssor.com/support.html) so that the tag also stretches and resizes with the slider when browser resizes?

Answer (score 0):

Please just do it as what you can imagine. See following,

```
    <div u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 1300px;
        height: 500px; overflow: hidden;">
        <div>
            <img u="image" src="../img/1920/red.jpg" />
            <h1>your content here</h1>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img u="image" src="../img/1920/red.jpg" />
            <h1>your content here</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
```